# Using Abs in MeshFunction gives incorrect results

Tags: plotting

Code:

```
data = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 100];
ListLinePlot[data, MeshFunctions -> {Abs[#2] &}, Mesh -> {1}, MeshShading -> {Red, Green}, MeshStyle -> None]
```

Picture:
[image: Mathematica plotting Abs wrong]

What's going on? I'm not looking for a workaround, as I'm going to be wanting to use a more complicated mesh function that includes `Abs`.

Comment: Not exactly the same, but very similar `ListLinePlot[data, MeshFunctions -> {(#2) &}, Mesh -> {{1, -1}},
 MeshShading -> {Red, Blue}, MeshStyle -> None]`

Comment: From the docs: "The `Subscript[m, i]` should normally be chosen to be continuous monotonic functions", where `Subscript[m, i]` represent the mesh functions.  `Abs` is not monotonic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you are using `MeshFunctions -> {Abs[#2] &}` to cause the curve to change color when it crosses `+1.5` and `-1.5`, but it does not.  This is because, although a line segment of `data` may cross one of those values, the corresponding line segment of `Abs[data]` does not necessarily do so.  For clarity, consider data modified by two additional points at `+3` and `-3`, with the goal of causing the color to change at exactly `+1.5` and `-1.5`.

```
data = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 100]; data = Append[data, 3]; data = Append[data, -3];
```

The plot in the Question (with `PlotRange -> {-3, 3}` added for clarity) is

```
ListLinePlot[data, MeshFunctions -> {Abs[#2] &}, Mesh -> {1}, 
 MeshShading -> {Red, Green}, MeshStyle -> None, PlotRange -> {-3, 3}]
```

[image: original]

The lines near `16`, for instance, do not change color.  Next, plot `Abs` of the same data

```
ListLinePlot[Abs[data], MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, Mesh -> {1}, 
 MeshShading -> {Red, Green}, MeshStyle -> None, PlotRange -> {-3, 3}]
```

[image: abs]

We see that lines of `Abs[data]` never cross `+1.5` at `16` and so do not change color.  Hence, they do not change color in the first plot eiher.

To assure the desired color change, the approach suggested by belisarius in his Comment seems preferable.

Comment: Ah, I see, the points that remain green jump from a large positive value to a large negative value! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, and their absolute values change much less.  This point was not obvious to me either until I plotted `Abs[data]`.  Thanks for accepting the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am not sure what your ultimate aim was. I note that `Mesh->{1}` is not specifying a value of the mesh but number of mesh points. I post this for clarification/facilitation:

```
data = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 100];
llp1 = ListLinePlot[data, MeshFunctions -> {Abs[#2] &}, Mesh -> {{1}},
    MeshShading -> {Red, Green}, MeshStyle -> None, 
   Epilog -> {Blue, PointSize[0.02], 
     Point[Thread[{Range[100], data}]]}, PlotLabel -> "Mesh->{{1}}"];
if = Interpolation[data, InterpolationOrder -> 1];
data = RandomReal[{-3, 3}, 100];
llp2 = Plot[if[x], {x, 1, 100}, MeshFunctions -> (Abs@#2 &), 
   Mesh -> {{1}}, MeshShading -> {Red, Green}, 
   PlotLabel -> "Using Interpolation"];
Column[{llp1, llp2}]
```

[image]